# printing a pattern using for loop by accepting a string

Tags: java, string

Sample input string:

> bluej

Output:

> ```
> b***b
> *l*l*
> **u**
> *e*e*
> j***j
> ```

(where '*' indicates a blank space)

I have done this much so far:

```
int n = s.length() - 1;
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= (n + 1); j++) {
        if (i == j || i == n - (j - 1))
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        else {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But output is:

> ```
> b****b
> *l**l*
> **uu**
> **ee**
> *j**j*
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `i == n-(j-1)` with `i == n - j` and second for loops `for (j = 0; j <= n+1; j++)` to `for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)` :

```
int n = s.length() - 1;
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
        if (i == j || i == n - j)
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        else {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: which one please mention?

Comment: Yes,It's required, please run this code. Its working perfectly according to your need. :)

Comment: We can clean up here, if you like, because these comments are not needed anymore :D.

Answer (score 2):

2nd loop termination condition should be `j<=n`.
if condition should be `(i == j || i == n - j)`

Testing your code in a debugger while checking the values of the involved variables would likely let you solve it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Look at the number of characters. You are displaying 6 characters, while the expected output displays 5 characters. You need to change the end of the inner for, like this:

```
for(j=0;j<=(n);j++)
```

Step 2: You are expecting to have `n+1` as the last index for `j`, but it was changed to `n`. You need to apply it:

```
if(i== j || i == n-(j))
```

Examples:

- i = 0, then the condition is true for j = 0 and j = 4
- i = 1, then the condition is true for j = 1 and j = 3
- i = 2, then the condition is true for j = 2
- i = 3, then the condition is true for j = 3 and j = 1
- i = 4, then the condition is true for j = 4 and j = 0

Answer (score 1):

It Works:

```
    String s = "bluej";
    int n = s.length() - 1;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= (n); j++) {
            if (i == j || i == n - (j))
                System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
            else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```